# Error deploying smart contract with web3.js and Truffle HD wallet provider

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

My web3 version is 1.0.0-beta.41,
node version is 10.15.1 
solc compiler is 0.4.25

compile.js is successfully compiled with interface and bytecode exports.

My deploy.js file

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');


const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
     "punch hello latin float quality thank armor shoulder quick daring tone tell",
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/c4683f6aea9f4e65a690b46d028dcc94"
 )

const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

When i do

```
 node deploy.js
```

I get this following error

```
          Error: Please provide an valid Web3 provider
        at ProviderResolver.resolve (/home/feynman/Programs/Ethereum/Ethmarket/node_modules/web3-providers/dist/web3-providers.cjs.js:720:13)
        at Web3.AbstractWeb3Module (/home/feynman/Programs/Ethereum/Ethmarket/node_modules/web3-core/dist/web3-core.cjs.js:27:51)
        at new Web3 (/home/feynman/Programs/Ethereum/Ethmarket/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.cjs.js:30:68)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/feynman/Programs/Ethereum/Ethmarket/deploy.js:11:14)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
        at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
        at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
        at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67736753/using-local-private-key-with-web3-js/67736754#67736754

Answer (score 0):

tuffle-hdwallet-provider is deprecated check  out the versions compatibility